# Retrofit Error when I try to get the data from the server

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I did the register functionality and it worked fine but when I want to get data from the server I ran into this problem.

Here is my retrofit class

```
public class ApiClient {

private static final String BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/LOGIN/";
public static Retrofit retrofit;

public static Retrofit getApiClient() {

    if (retrofit == null){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }

    return retrofit;
}
}
```

and this is my Interface

```
public interface AccountInterface {

 @FormUrlEncoded
 @POST("Register.php")
 Call<String> registerUser(@Field("username") String username,  @Field("password") String password, @Field("name") String name);

 @FormUrlEncoded
 @POST("index.php")
 Call<LoginResponse> loginUser(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);

}
```

LoginResponse Class

```
public class LoginResponse {

User user;

public LoginResponse(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public LoginResponse() {
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
 }
}
```

User class

```
public class User {
private int user_id;
private String name;
private String password;
private String username;


public User(int id, String name, String password, String username) {
    this.user_id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    this.username = username;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public int getId() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.user_id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

Here How I call it

```
 public void saveData(View view) {

    RegisterInterface service = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(RegisterInterface.class);
    Call<LoginResponse> login = service.loginUser(username.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString());

    login.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {

            Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: call  "+ response.body().getUser().getUsername()); 

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: "+ t.toString());
        }
    });

}
```

the index.php file

```
include_once("db.php");
include_once("LoginResponse.php");
include_once("User.php");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statment = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username =? AND password = ?");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statment,"ss", $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statment) or die( mysqli_stmt_error($statment) );

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statment);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statment,$userID,$name,$username,$password);

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statment)){

  $user = new User($userID,$name,$password,$username);
  $response = new LoginResponse($user);

}

 echo json_encode($response);
}
```

and this is the result using postman

```
{"user":{"user_id":20,"name":"user1","password":"123123","username":"username1"}}
```

this is the error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

I want to display the user data in the page.
How do I solve this? 
thanks for your help

Comment: I guess the response is different than you expect. Can you post the json string of your response?

Comment: this is the json that the API returns {"user_id":20,"name":"user1","password":"123123","username":"username1"} when accessing it in a browser

Comment: Can you replace User with String in AccountInterface and post what you get: 
    Call<String> login = service.loginUser(username.getText().toString(),password.getText().toStrng());

       login.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
   
       public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
          // please post what you get here calling response.body()
      }
   
       public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
          // or here t.toString()

     }

Comment: I've modified it as you said and the log message prints  ( <br  ) only

Comment: It seems you don't get the response. I guess something is wrong in index.php file

Comment: I've added index.php file in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're returning a dictionary json only. It gets interpreted as a String by retrofit. If you want it to return an object you should add another level in your json, something like `{{"user_id":20,"name":"user1","password":"123123","username":"username1"}}`

Also, it is better if you created a class called LoginResponse and wrap the user in it. Then you'd change your json to model that class. Like so:

```
public class LoginResponse {

    User user;

    public LoginResponse(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public LoginResponse() {
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

`{"user":{"user_id":20,"name":"user1","password":"123123","username":"username1"}}`

Of course that would change the way you call retrofit, instead of calling over User you'd call it over LoginResponse.

Comment: the error still exist. How do I get the correct json data from the API? I've modified the question with the updated code

Comment: You're probably receiving a different response in retrofit than the one in Postman. Are you sure you're sending the params (username and password) correctly? What about the API interface, is the endpoint correctly configured? I'm asking this because you'll get that error if your API returns anything else except the json.

Comment: It was an error in index.php when getting the data I was using a wrong function.

Comment: Thanks Levi for the valuable information and your time.

Answer (score 0):

Create your User class as :

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("user_id")
@Expose
private Integer userId;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;
@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;

public Integer getUserId() {
return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
this.userId = userId;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getPassword() {
return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
this.password = password;
}

public String getUsername() {
return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
this.username = username;
}

}
```

Comment: still the same error  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $